# jquery mobile and three.js make document load twice

Tags: jquery, mobile, three.js

I'm fooling around with jquery mobile and three.js.

Here is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>   
    <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    var camera, scene, renderer;
    var geometry, material, mesh;

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
        camera.position.z = 1000;

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
        material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true } );

        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( mesh );

        renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        $(document).live("vclick", function (evt) {
            alert('list click');
        }); 
    }

    function animate() {

        // note: three.js includes requestAnimationFrame shim
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );


        mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
        mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

        renderer.render( scene, camera );

    }

    </script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

It's an example from three.js, which works fine. Although if I include jquery mobile and jquery library, the document loads twice. (there is a rectangle, if you scroll down there is a rotating cube and there is a text "loading" twice on the bottom.)

Could someone explain whats going on? I only included the two jquery libraries.

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't wrapping your `init` in a `$(document).ready` or `pageinit` handler? My guess is that the jQM messes with what your JS has already created, so you should do that after the jQM has initialized the page.

Comment: Please have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzztJ/). I can't figure out exactly what is the issue ?

Comment: Valay: vclick doesnt seem to work. if i try it on localhost (WAMP), it hangs at "define([
 'require',
 './widgets/loader',..." <- jquery mobile file.

Comment: Please try to run the code from this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzztJ/1/) and let me know. I hope you can figure out the issue for your requirement.

Comment: Valay: thanks, but your fiddle hangs. i can see the red rectangle, but doesnt animate, only the ui-icon ui-icon-loading icon is over it. btw the vclick works, so jquery mobile is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is a jquery mobile quirk.  Try moving your scripts to `head`, not `body`.  If that doesn't fix it, move your three.js code inside jqm's pageinit:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
     // your code here...
})
```